# How to drop memory when a parallelized for-loop finishes iteration in Julia?

Tags: memory-management, parallel-processing, julia, ram

I am wondering if there's a way for Julia to "drop" any memory that was created during a parallelized for-loop instance. For example, in

```
Threads.@threads for k in 1:3
    LargeVariable=functionThatReturnsLargeVariable(parameters,k)
end
```

I would have 3 threads obtain LargeVariable, which takes up more than 1/3 of my computer's memory. Right now, Julia retains those variables in each core, which would cause my computer to crash once the third core catches up to the first two. (I'm assuming here that the cores take varying amounts of time to run the for-loop iterations). Is there a way that I can force Julia to delete any new memory created in the for-loop once each iteration has completed?

Comment: Not an answer as I'm not 100% sure, but would something like this work for you ?
`LargeVariable = nothing; # dereference the content of LargeVariable \n
GC.gc(); # force garbage collection`

Comment: @Amon That's a great suggestion. I was hoping for something more automatic, like a parameter to pass to Threads, but this will certainly work!

Comment: As an additionnal precision, instead of giving `nothing` to your `LargeVariable`, you may want to give it something of the same type in order to keep type consistent (and help the compiler optimize your code). For example, if `LargeVariable` is an array of `BigFloat` it will be better to write `LargeVariable = Vector{BigFloat}()` that way you give an empty array (low memory usage but same type).